# MYSQL: Alternative for INNER JOIN with BIG TABLES (It is too slow)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, phpmyadmin

I have two tables (They are bigger with more of 200,000 rows, this is just an example)

```
Table1:temptable
id         |Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative | QUAL | MQ
........................................................................
NULL         chr1       12334  12335    A          TT            10   20
NULL         chr1       12334  12335    C          TT            5    3
NULL         chr2       123    123      A           T            1    2
NULL         chr2       34     34       A           T            11   60
NULL         chr3       12     12       A           T            6    NULL
```

```
Table2:TableVariants2
id          | Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative 
.............................................................
1            chr1          12334  12335   A        TT
2            chr1          12334  12335   C        TT
3            chr2          123    123     A         T
4            chr2          34     34      A         T
5            chr3          12     12      A         T
```

I want to merge them based on equal Chromosome, Start, End, Reference and Alternative and obtain:

```
id         |Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative | QUAL | MQ
........................................................................
1           chr1       12334  12335     A             TT         10     20
2           chr1       12334  12335     C             TT         5      3
3           chr2       123    123       A              T         1      2
4           chr2       34     34        A              T         11     60
5           chr3       12     12        A              T         6     NULL
```

I have tried the following but it is too slow for big tables and I need something faster

```
SELECT B.Maxid, A.Chromosome, A.Start, A.End, A.Reference, A.Alternative , A.QUAL,A.MQ 
FROM temptable A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT `Chromosome`, `Start`, `End`, `Reference`,`Alternative`, MAX(id) AS Maxid FROM TableVariants2 GROUP BY `Chromosome`, `Start`, `End`, `Reference`,`Alternative`) B
ON A.Chromosome=B.Chromosome AND A.Start=B.Start AND A.End=B.End AND A.Reference=B.Reference AND A.Alternative=B.Alternative
```

There is any alternative to the INNER JOIN in order to speed up the query?

Comment: Can you add table and index definitions. Add explain output too. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: What do you mean "alternative"? An `INNER JOIN` is one of the basic parts of every RDBMS. If it's slow it means that either your query is written poorly (perhaps non-SARGable arguments), or you have no indexes to help the RDBMS return the data set; thus it's as fast as `x` table scans *(where `x` is the numbers of tables referenced in your query (if a table if referenced twice, for example in the `FROM`, that is 2 tables)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow a few things while writing a query:

```
1. Analyze your data.
2. Make sure you have created necessary indexes.
3. In Select statement write only required column, avoid unnecessary columns.
4. Do not write subquery or co-related query until and unless is required.
```

Let's see if you follow these steps could help.
But Inner Join is the basic join which cannot be replaced if you have to join two tables.

Comment: I just need to create the indexes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(Chromosome, Start, End, Reference, Alternative, id)` -- in the same order as the `GROUP BY`.